# What does the field of mathematical biology study?

Tags: soft-question

I like math and bio and I want to study both. There is a subject called mathematical biology. What is it? What does a mathematical biologist do? What institutions have good mathematical biology programs?

Comment: How can you like math and bio at the same time?

Comment: I do I know it may sound weird but can't there be an exception and I am sure there are others too!

Comment: Maybe it is that you don't like any of them... they are **very** different ways... studying at higher levels reveals the intricacies of a subject.

Comment: @Awesome what exactly you wanna say?

Comment: I also wonder where you are going with these statements, @Awesome. The second one, in particular... might not be the best thing I have read on the site.

Comment: @IdeedRafiqi: It is perfectly fine to like both math and bio.....

Comment: They do a lot of modelling, they use a lot of numerical analysis, statistics, and concepts from physics. If you stray away from the "applied" side, they also work on a lot of SDEs.

Comment: @nameless SDE's ?

Comment: @ideed Stochastic Differential Equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematical biology asks many different questions.  An intro course will look at things like population genetics (the study of the dynamics of gene propagation in populations) and basic bioinformatics.  But any use of mathematical models in biology is in this field, and it can get fairly deeply mathematical.  René Thom's classic "Structural Stability and Morphogenesis" applies algebraic topology and catastrophe theory to the modelling of biological structure.  Knot theory is found in the study of DNA recombination and the action of enzymes like topoisomerase.  Physiology and pharmacological dynamics all study rate equations over complex metabolic graphs.  Nonequilibrium thermodynamics and dissipative structures are studied in the realm of biogenesis.  Autocatalytic sets, fitness landscapes, etc. are modelled in basic information evolution studies.

The field is really as it sounds - it is the application of mathematics to biology.